# How to execute a function after another function has executed a given number of times?

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function like this

```
checkconnection();
```

I want to execute it 5 times before this function below triggers:

```
console.log('cant connect. Try again later');
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive function and a counter variable that counts up to 5.

```js
let cntr = 1;

function checkconnection(){
   if(cntr == 5){
      console.log('cant connect. Try again later');
   }
   else{
     cntr ++;
     checkconnection();
   }
}

checkconnection();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make another function out of it using another function... this technique is called memoization.

```js
function checkConnection() {
  console.log("checking connnection");
}

// let's limit it to 5
var checkConnection = limiter(checkConnection);

function limiter(func, times) {
  var i = 0
  times = times || 5
  return function() {
    if (i++ < times) {
      func()
    } else {
      console.log("stop running after 5 times");
    }
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  checkConnection();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a rate limiter function. Best to search NPM for a library, but I implemented such a function below.

The following code configures an array to hold the timestamps of the previous few invocations. If the period over which `n+1` calls have been made is greater than the period permitted for `n` calls, then the invocation of the limited function is permitted, otherwise an `onExcess` function is called.

I am playing around with an expression-oriented style of JS, hence the unusual coding style below:

```js
const nop = () => {}
const log = console.log
const circularArray = (maxLength = 0, 
                       arr = new Array(maxLength).fill(-Infinity)) => 
    ({ 
        push: () => ((arr.length >= maxLength && arr.shift()),
                      arr.push(performance.now())),
        get earliest() { return arr[0] },
        get latest() { return arr[maxLength - 1] } 
     })


const limiter = ({ times = 1, 
                   period = 1000, 
                   onExcess = nop }) => 
                       (fn, 
                        fiveCalls = circularArray(times + 1)) => // +1 because all `times` calls are permitted in the period
    (...args) =>
        (fiveCalls.push(),
         ((fiveCalls.latest - fiveCalls.earliest) > period) 
            ? fn(...args)
            : onExcess())

const onExcess = () => log('Rate limit exceeded.')
const limit = limiter({ times: 5, period: 1000, onExcess })
const checkConnection = (x) => log(`${x}. checking connection...`)
const limitedCheckConnection = limit(checkConnection)

let x = 0
for(;x < 6; x++) limitedCheckConnection(x) // call SIX times
setTimeout(() => limitedCheckConnection(x), 1000) // x is now 6 (note call six was discarded!), having been incremented after the final sixth iteration
```